# Testing against MacOS Big Sur without having suitable MacOS machine

Tags: java, macos, macos-big-sur

I sell a Java based application on MacOS and need to test it against Big Sur.

I have two MacOS computers but neither can be upgraded to *Big Sur*, at some point I will have to invest in a new machine but by default they use the new *G1* cpu, and currently there is no Java jdk for this so if I purchased a G1 machine it would be no use for testing. I could purchase a new *Intel* machine instead but then I wouldn't be able to test Java on G1 when it did become available, and would have to but another machine.

So is there a way I can rent a Mac remotely and try it out, need to be able to use the Gui not just a Terminal ?

I have had a look but couldn't find anything.

Comment: take a look https://github.com/barrykn/big-sur-micropatcher

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Cleafy/sxkdvm or https://www.macincloud.com/

Comment: @PaulWhelan For sxkdvm, can we do it on Windows ?

Comment: @PaulWhelan it syas for macincloud access is via rdp, is this remote desktop and if so is this only available from a BigSur machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macincloud.com worked reasonably well, but i have seinced moved to purchasing a physical G1 machine since it can  use Java via Rosetta emulation